# Java Android finish activity , start previous activity

Tags: java, android

I have a 2 activity A and B . 
In activity A I start activity B . On activity B I want to do photo and go back to activity A and do next step.

In activity A I have :

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

In activity B I have

```
buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                        startActivity();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

 private void startActivity(){
Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
setResult(REQUEST_CAMERA, output);
finish();
```

}

And on Activity A I have :

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how on Activity B put fileUri and start good method on activity A

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new ImageTask().execute(data);
            clearCamera();
        }
    };
```

Comment: from activity 2 you are starting camera?

Comment: You need to use [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) method.

Comment: @VishalSanghani on Activity 1 I start a camera (camera is a activity B)

Comment: So you want to capture an image and get result back in activity A ?? Right

Comment: @rana_sadam Yes but I don't want to use a system camera I have to use my camera (I use a camera api)

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example

Comment: @AnkurJain I added setResultI edit my post , but when I take a photo I go to Activity A and nothing is happend

Comment: @AnkurJain i changed a method  startActivity()

Comment: Can you please post your `jpegCallback`.

Comment: @AnkurJain I paste this method

Comment: I guess you are saving captured image in `ImageTask().execute(data);`. After saving image you need to get URI and then call your `startActivity` method in Activity B.

Comment: You dont need to start activity A again, just set result and finish B

Comment: @AnkurJain yes I saving capture image in ImageTask().execute(data);
 
next onPostExecute() I startActivity but nothing happend in start Activity

Comment: Then after saving get the URI of saved image and then call your `startActivity` method in Activity B.

Comment: @AnkurJain I do what you say but still it is not working

Comment: Retrieve URI `intent.getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)` in your Activity A.

Comment: @AnkurJain where I have to do this ?

Comment: @AnkurJain I paste this onActivityResult but still it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
setResult(RESULT_OK, output);//change this
finish();
```

Comment: In your `onActivityResult` method of Activity A.

Comment: make sure you have get result in `onActivityResult` in Activity A, debug it and check your conditions.